# array.push not working within ajax and for loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

I am running an ajax to get a JSON object from a database. With this data I am trying to pass some parts into an array but it keeps coming up undefined.

The success object from ajax is stored in data.

I setup an array called username2
I then get object length
run a for loop and try to push the object data[]['user'] into the array.

the code is below followed by my console log for each username2 I am getting undefined. Am I missing something silly

```
        var username2 = [];
        count = Object.keys(data).length;

        for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
            var test1 = data[i]['user'];
            username2.push(test1);
            console.log(i);
            console.log('test1 : ' + test1);
            console.log('username2 : ' + username2[i]);
        }

 1
 test1 : sean
 username2 : undefined
 2
 test1 : berk
 username2 : undefined
 3
 test1 : erbwr
 username2 : undefined
 4
 test1 : svs
 username2 : undefined
 5
 test1 : dad
 username2 : undefined
 6
 test1 : vdhbt
 username2 : undefined
```

Comment: Your for is iterating from `1` and array is indexing from `0`. Thus `push` is always off by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please start iteration from 0 as given below

```
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var test1 = data[i]['user'];
        username2.push(test1);
        console.log(i);
        console.log('test1 : ' + test1);
        console.log('username2 : ' + username2[i]);
    }
```

Comment: thank you what a simply mistake. I wanted to start with 1 for the object and forgot the array starting at 0. all working now. been staring at this for ages and could not see it